# Select two columns from two different tables each with different column names

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm having trouble figuring out this query. I'm using PHP and postgresql 9.1. I want to be able to select fields from rows based on a criteria in another field like so.

Table `A` has columns:

```
vid, title, description, col4, col5, col6, col7
```

Table `B` has columns:

```
pid, title, description, colx, coly
```

I want to search `title` and `description` from both tables and if a match is found, return the `vid` or `pid` of the row it was found in.

What I've tried so far:

```
SELECT vid FROM tableA WHERE title LIKE %somevalue%
UNION
SELECT pid FROM tableB WHERE title LIKE %somevalue%
```

Problem is when I do that and it finds a match for `tableB` which returns the correct value but assigned to `vid` column in the array.
The php array displays

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [vid] => 100007 ) )
```

When it should be

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [pid] => 100007 ) )
```

It doesn't give me the correct column name for the table. It only gives me the column name of the first select statement.
Also, it only returns one or the other. If the value is found in both I want both values with both columns.

Comment: Surely someone knows how to combine select statements to get the correct results. Since union is not correct, what subqueries will work instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  a.vid,
  b.pid
FROM (
  SELECT vid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vid) AS rn
  FROM tableA
  WHERE title LIKE '%somevalue%'
) a
FULL JOIN (
  SELECT pid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pid) AS rn
  FROM tableB
  WHERE title LIKE '%somevalue%'
) b
ON a.rn = b.rn
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm looking for. Don't quite know how it works but it works. Although I would rather it not bring back the column if its empty, it still is the best answer and works how I want. I'll use PHP to handle the empty key/value I guess.

Comment: The result of a query is supposed to contain a fixed set of columns. If you want it to be dynamic, the query itself should be built dynamically. Not sure if PostgreSQL allows you to build and execute dynamic queries, but I've no doubts the final query would be more complex than any of the solutions offered here. So yes, handling empty values in the client code is a good idea, that's what I would most likely choose to do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like:

```
SELECT 'vid' AS key, vid,  NULL AS pid FROM tableA WHERE title LIKE ...
UNION
SELECT 'pid',        NULL, pid         FROM tableB WHERE title LIKE ...
```

Comment: doesn't work correct as I need it to. Does the same as Martin's

Comment: @Pjack: In that case, it sounds like you don't actually want a `UNION`!

Comment: Ok then what do I need to retrieve two column names that it finds the values in?

Comment: @Pjack: My answer supplies that. If you're not satisfied with it, then I think you're out of luck.

Comment: No it doesn't exactly. It will return additional columns but not in the correct way. I need it to say pid->100007 and vid->100342 if it finds two results in both columns. Yours gives empty column names and will not work with my php array functions. So it really does not supply that.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible with a single query and a UNION.  According to w3schools, the columns are forced to match the first select statement when you use a UNION.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: nothing useful :/ all it does is pull the column name Array ( [0] => Array ( [vid] => 100007 [pid] => ) )  but it should not even have vid in there should be Array ( [0] => Array ( [pid] => 100007 ) )

Comment: I believe that SQL will force all results to have the same columns when you perform a union.  Why not just run two queries?

Comment: Ok then what do I need to retrieve two column names that it finds the values in? It needs to be in one statement and not good with sub selects.

Comment: Citing W3S (see http://w3fools.com) as an authority on anything will only get you in trouble, the PostgreSQL manual is much better and it is accurate (unlike W3S) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
   SELECT vid as 'id', 'isVid' as idType  FROM tableA WHERE title LIKE ...
    UNION
   SELECT pid as 'id', 'isPid' as idType  FROM tableB WHERE title LIKE ...
```